# startx fails after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, xorg

```
[   261.695] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   261.695] Current Operating System: Linux cylon4 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64
[   261.695] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic root=UUID=92ca9aba-714f-44b1-ad63-97b305239d37 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
[   261.695] xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   261.695] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   261.695]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   261.695] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   261.695] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Dec 27 08:24:32 2023
[   261.696] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   261.698] (==) ServerLayout "layout"
[   261.698] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   261.698] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   261.698] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   261.698] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   261.698] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   261.698] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   261.698] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   261.698] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   261.698] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   261.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   261.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   261.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   261.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   261.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   261.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   261.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   261.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   261.700] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   261.700]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   261.700] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   261.700] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   261.700] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   261.700] (II) Loader magic: 0x55b75066e020
[   261.700] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   261.700]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   261.700]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[   261.700]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[   261.700]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   261.704] (--) using VT number 2
```

Comment: there is nothing here to  go  on. please have a search on AU for similar topics and see if those have any commands you can add the info off. your desktop should be on tty2 looking at the last line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's helpful if the question is clear; I see no basic *software stack* details provided (ie. what OS & release are you using), details are given of a kernel (used by multiple products/releases, so which are you using??) etc. Are you hoping we guess?  Why not just tell us what you're running, so they can can concentrate on what is possibly your problem, rather than trying to work out what you're using?

Comment: Key error is '"Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices" How do I identify busIDs?